# MIPS sorting pre-stored strings alphabetically

Tags: mips

I need help sorting pre-stored strings in alphabetical order, this is the code already given:

```
.data

String1:
    .asciiz "Applebee"      
String2: 
    .asciiz "subway"        
String3:
    .asciiz "Fire House"    
String4:
    .asciiz "Red Lobster"   
String5:
    .asciiz "Moe's"
```

I am able to hardcode this so that I get the result I want but I want to know how to do it with an algorithm so a user can enter any name they want and the the program will sort them based on the first letter of each one.

I've added some code so that I can go to the next line as well as state the before and after:

```
before:
    .asciiz "Here are the words given:"
after:
    .asciiz "Here are the words sorted:"
newLine:
    .asciiz "\n"
```

Now I have hardcoded the entire thing:

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    li $v0,4    #"Here are the words:"
    la $a0,before
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    #-----------------------
    #words
    li $v0,4        
    la $a0,String1
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String2
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String3
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String4
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String5
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    #-----------------------
    li $v0,4    #"Here are the words sorted:"
    la $a0,after
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    #-----------------------
    #sorted words
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String1
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String3
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String5
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String4
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,newLine
    syscall
    li $v0,4
    la $a0,String2
    syscall
    #-----------------------
    la $v0, 10      #exit program
    syscall
```

I think a way to do this would be to get the alphabet and convert them to numbers and then somehow take in the first character of each word and sort the numbers.

Then sort the numbers and print the words associated with the numbers.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46868524/alphabetical-sort-in-mips

Comment: and nobody has answered that question either

Comment: You want to implement something like [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/). Then plug that into whatever sorting algorithm you want, to compare pairs of strings, and decide how you want to swap pairs of strings (e.g. swap pointers in a string table, or swap the actual string contents).